# Extjs tpl for number format

Tags: extjs4.2

I am new to Extjs. 
How can I formatting number in tpl?

Here is my code:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    tpl: [
        '<p>Number: {myDataNumber}</p>'
    ]
}
```

I have been searching Extjs API for tpl. But I didn't find formating number for tpl.
Would you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExtJS tpl allow for easy formatting using methods from the `Ext.util.Format` class, which can be implemented with the following syntax:

```
<p>Number: {myDataNumber:number( "0.00" )}</p>
```

Of course, you can specify whatever format you need for the number formatting.

Also, if none of the built in format functions work, you could always add to `Ext.util.Format`  (it's a singleton) or specify a custom member function (see `Ext.XTemplate` docs) for the specific template. Either way, you can implement any format you could imagine...just depends on what the best way is based on your requirements.